# Move view when screen is touched

Tags: android, multithreading, animation, 2d

I have a Button, and when the user touches it I want the Button to start moving.

## Move a button (with fixed speed) on a relative layout after the screen has been touched

I tried to use a thread to generate the movement.

Here is the code reduced to the minimum, the solution might be completly different...

**FragmentGameBoard** : Fragment containing the `RelativeLayout` with the button. Here it is a fragment but it could actually be the same in a MainActivity

```
public class FragmentGameBoard extends Fragment {

    private MovingButton btn;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Instanciation du Layout fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gameboard, container, false);
        btn = (MovingButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn);

        btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    //TODO Move button
                    btn.buttonThread.run();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

**MovingButton** : Attemp to extend button in order to have its own thread to move

```
public class MovingButton extends Button {

    public ButtonThread buttonThread;

    public MovingButton(Context context){
        super(context);
        buttonThread = new ButtonThread(this);
    }

    public MovingButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        buttonThread = new ButtonThread(this);
    }

    public MovingButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        buttonThread = new ButtonThread(this);
    }

}
```

**ButtonThread** : Thread I try to launch

```
public class ButtonThread implements Runnable {

    private MovingButton movingButton;

    public ButtonThread(MovingButton movingButton) {
        this.movingButton = movingButton;
    }

    public void run(){
        float x = movingButton.getX();
        float y = movingButton.getX();
        while(movingButton.getX()>5) {
            movingButton.setX(x - 1);

            try {
                synchronized (this) {
                    this.wait(5); // To have something like fps
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                System.out.println("interruption");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I really have no idea how to do it. It is actually entering the while loop (and looping) but the button is not moving. (I must say I'm not really surprised...)

I am new to android development and I might be totally wrong.

Thank you for your help !

NB : I intend to have a random movement with algorithm for the button, animation won't be enough.

Comment: Your view animation must refresh at main thread.You can use Handler to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Update UI must call at main thread.
If you want move your button,use property animation is better way.

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(btn, "translationX", 0f, 360f).setDuration(1000).start();
```

Comment: Thank you but I intend to specify a specific movement, that never stops (playing with random and distances from parent's borders). Animation won't make it I guess.